# How to mantain cookie from different subdomain?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

I have a simple html page served from my local machine by an app running on port 8000, using the domain `appdev.my_company.com`.

The same app serves an API from the domain `appcenter.my_company.com`.

I have an endpoint in said API which sets a session cookie header that looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie:gac_3_6e...="VC1_69...=="; Domain=.my_company.com; Path=/
```

I made an ajax request to said endpoint, from the static page, hoping that the cookie would be set since the domain is the same (only the subdomain differs):

```
/* In http://appdev.my_company.com:8000 */
$.ajax({
    url: "http://appcenter.my_company.com:8000/login/",
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(){
        console.log("logged in");
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});
```

But it doesn't.

The cookie needs to be associated in the browser window with the current domain, because we need to reload a plugin that picks up this cookie (the cookie comes from a thrid party server).

How can I get this cookie to be registered in the browser? If I look into the resources tab of the web console, no cookie shows up.

I took a look at [domain matching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.3) of the [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), and it appears this should work.

What can be wrong in this case?

Comment: Different ports = different domains. You can't share cookies between different domains. Sorry. You'd need to use cross-window events with a frame on that different domain and something like `window.postMessage` to get the data.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sadly the ports have nothing to do with it, according to RFC6265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). This is the exact problem they try to solve. The only other way (to my knowledge) is to proxy the requests to the other source via your server.

Comment: @Alvaro Did you use CORS?

Comment: Yes, I worked on setting the correct headers from the server side and updated the Ajax request to allowCredentials

Comment: Please +1 my answer if it worked for you, then. This helps other locate it for similar problems. Good luck with your project!